# Print only one link of the web with python3 web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I´m trying to print the link o text of each headline of the following website   `http://www.infobolsa.es/news` but when I run the code I keep getting the same output, the correct headline text but every link is the same. Here is the part of the link code, thank you:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html_page = urlopen("http://www.infobolsa.es/news")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')
links = list()
for titleM in bodyDictWeb2:
    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/news/detail")}):
        print(link)
        bodyDictWeb2[titleM] = link.get('href')
        break


for k,v in bodyDictWeb2.items():
    print(k,":",v)
```

Comment: why there is a `break` in the second for loop? it will basically get the first one and then breaks out. and what is `bodyDictWeb2`?

Comment: You can use this xpath `//article/a[@class="title"]` to get all headlines.

Comment: Whats bodyDictWeb2? And you want only the text of the headlines eg: "EL IBEX 35 FIRMA SU PEOR ENERO DESDE 2016 POR EL CORONAVIRUS DE CHINA" ?

Comment: @NavidZarepak I put the break so there's only one link per headline. bodyDictWeb is a dictionary with all the headines.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, here is the code that works:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html_page = urlopen("http://www.infobolsa.es/news")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')
links = list()
for titleM in bodyDictWeb2:
    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/news/detail")}):
        print(link.text , link.get('href'))
    break
```